# Conditionally prepending a string to mail subject in Exim4

Tags: email, email-server, exim, mailing-list

I have a custom solution for implementing mailing lists using only Exim4 and a SQL database. Basically, most of the hard work is done in a single router, which checks on various conditions, does list-members lookup, adds new header fields, modifies subject etc. It also works acceptably well for our needs, with only one issue.

I prepend the friendly name of the mailing list to the subject line. Currently, the list name is prepended every time a mail passes through, so after long discussions, a subject line looks like "[ListName] Re: [ListName] Re: [ListName] Re: ...". Obviously, I'd like to prepend the name of the list only once, e.g. it should be prepended only if the name tag is not already in the subject. Any ideas what is the easiest way to achieve this?

There is no need for it to be a router-only solution, but I'd like to avoid piping to an external program and then feeding the mail back into the mail system. There must be an easier way to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring the prefix or subject in an ACL variable. This can must be done in the data ACL.  Use this variable as the new subject in the router.   Something like this should work.

```
warn
    acl_m5 = $h_subject:
    !condition =  ${if match{$h_subject:}{/N[ListName]/N}}
    acl_m5 = [ListName]: $h_subject:
```

You could also conditionally define a variable in the acl and wrap the subject line in a conditional inclusion.

Comment: [ListName] depends on the recipient address, and $recipients in an ACL contains all the recipients from the header, potentially multiple ones. So this solution is not perfect in the general case, but it did give me a very usefull hint for implementing the same thing in the router. Basically, doing the if-match to construct the subject in the router.